# Как вывести массив с помощью foreach в html таблицу

Tags: php, html

```
[0] => stdClass Object(
  [id] => 1 [name] => Yandex [url] => http: //www.yandex.ru [status] => 1
)

[1] => stdClass Object(
  [id] => 2 [name] => VKontakte [url] => http; //www.vk.com [status] => 1
)

[2] => stdClass Object(
  [id] => 3 [name] => Google [url] => http: //www.google.co [status] => 1
)

[3] => stdClass Object(
  [id] => 4 [name] => Mail.ru [url] => http: //www.mail.ru [status] => 1
)

[4] => stdClass Object(
  [id] => 5 [name] => Rambler [url] => http: //www.rambler.r [status] => 1
)
```

Надо что бы эти данные через цикл `foreach` заполнялись в таблицу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table>
<?php foreach($array as $val) : ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $val->name; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Я вам привел пример,а дальше стройте структуру таблицы как вам угодно.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: array

Filename: views/welcome_message.php

Line Number: 29

Backtrace:

File: H:\home\test1.ru\www\application\views\welcome_message.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: H:\home\test1.ru\www\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 18
Function: view

File: H:\home\test1.ru\www\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: 29 <?php foreach($array as $val) : ?>

Comment: вместо `$array` укажите название вашего массива

Comment: Все норм я тут ошибку сам сделал спасибо