# Нужен цикл для заполнения столбца таблицы кнопками

Tags: html

```
<table id="node" border="1">
    <caption>Table</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>url</td>
        <td>status</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($url_list as $val) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo  $val->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->url; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->status; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

 </table>
```

Вот код

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой вопрос, что бы было понятнее чего вы хотите. (В какой столбец? Какие кнопки? И т.п.)

Comment: Я имею таблицу в html, последний столбец в этой таблице нужно циклом заполнить кнопками

Comment: Измените вопрос добавив в него код таблицы и уточним свой вопрос

Comment: @Yuri видимо код тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603328/

Comment: <table id="node" border="1">
  <caption>Table</caption>
  <tr>
   <td>id</td>
   <td>name</td>
   <td>url</td>
   <td>status</td>
   <td>Delete</td>
   <td>Edit</td>
  </tr>
        <?php foreach($url_list as $val) : ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo  $val->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $val->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $val->url; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $val->status; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
 
     </table>

Comment: Я добавил столбец с именем Delete

Comment: Нужно этот столбец таблицы заполнить кнопками

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот. Но заполнить кнопками его можно и в php коде ещё

```js
$(function() {
  for(var i = 1;i < $('#node tr').length;i++){
    $('#node tr').eq(i).append('<td><button data-id="delete-'+i+'">Delete</button></td><td><button data-id="edit-'+i+'">Edit</button></td>')
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="node" border="1"> 
  <caption>Table</caption> 
  <tr> <td>id</td> <td>name</td> <td>url</td> <td>status</td> <td>Delete</td> <td>Edit</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr><td>1</td> <td>name1</td> <td>http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</td> <td>1</td></tr> 
  <tr><td>2</td> <td>name2</td> <td>http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</td> <td>1</td></tr> 
  <tr><td>3</td> <td>name3</td> <td>http://ru.stackoverflow.com/</td> <td>0</td></tr> 
</table>
```